# Add array data into a sortedlist

Tags: c#, sortedlist

I'm trying to find a way where I can extend my extracted Array List into Sorted List? Here's the code I have below which displays the results horizontally based on each candidate, however I'm seeing how I can then incorporate this into SortedList where I can sort by the precinct?

I tried a few variations with the Sorted List, however my only success was printing out the first column (only) vertically.

X 012

X 075

X 050

X 040

```
string[] voting = { "X012033001140", "C075100026080", "A050070060100", "Q040088050090" };
//int length = voting.Length;
int starter = 0;

int total_a = 0;
int total_b = 0;
int total_c = 0;
int total_d = 0;

int precinct_x = 0;

Console.WriteLine("VOTING RESULTS");
Console.WriteLine("--------------------");

Console.WriteLine("Precinct\tCandidate A \tCandidate B\tCandidate C\tCandidate D\tTotal Precinct Votes");

while (starter < voting.Length)
{
    string precinct = voting[starter].Substring(0, 1);
    string cand_a = voting[starter].Substring(1, 3);
    string cand_b = voting[starter].Substring(4, 3);
    string cand_c = voting[starter].Substring(7, 3);
    string cand_d = voting[starter].Substring(10, 3);
    int counter = 0;

    //Converting the vote counts from strings to ints in order to calculate
    int a = Convert.ToInt32(cand_a);
    int b = Convert.ToInt32(cand_b);
    int c = Convert.ToInt32(cand_c);
    int d = Convert.ToInt32(cand_d);

    precinct_x = a + b + c + d;
    counter++;

    //Console.WriteLine(precinct);
    Console.WriteLine(precinct + "\t\t" + cand_a + "\t\t" + cand_b + "\t\t" + cand_c + "\t\t" + cand_d + "\t\t" + precinct_x + "\t");

    double precinct_total = Convert.ToDouble(precinct_x);

    //This is required in order to continuously loop up to the maximum of the voting Length
    starter = starter + 1;

    //Calculations for Candidate A
    total_a = total_a + a;

    total_b = total_b + b;
    total_c = total_c + c;
    total_d = total_d + d;

}
Console.WriteLine("\nTOTAL RESULTS");
Console.WriteLine("--------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
Console.WriteLine("\t\t" + total_a + "\t\t" + total_b + "\t\t" + total_c + "\t\t" + total_d);

Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: You're using terms too loosely. .NET has `Array`, `ArrayList`, and `SortedArray` classes. They all have built in sorting capabilities that you can customize. Your question makes it sound like you're using them all.

Comment: Ok, yeah my question is specifically targeting "SortedList", as I believe this might be an ideal solution to sort my data.After I've de-assembled my data from the original array string "string{} voting", I'm seeing how I can then incorporate this into "SortedList" so I can sort by the "precinct".

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to create a class that can hold the data to be sorted

```
public class VotingResult
{
    public VotingResult(int numberOfCandidates)
    {
        Candidates = new int[numberOfCandidates];
    }

    public string Precinct { get; set; }
    public int[] Candidates { get; private set; }
    public int PrecinctTotal { get { return Candidates.Sum(); } }
}
```

Then fill a list

```
const int NumberOfCandidates = 4;
var votingResults = new List<VotingResult>();
foreach (string s in voting) {
    votingResult = new VotingResult(NumberOfCandidates);
    votingResult.Precinct = s.Substring(0, 1);
    for (int cand = 0; cand < NumberOfCandidates; cand++) {
        votingResult.Candidates[cand] = Convert.ToInt32(s.Substring(3 * cand + 1, 3));
    }
    votingResults.Add(votingResult);
}
```

Now you can sort the list

```
var sortedResults = votingResults.OrderBy(v => v.Precinct);

// Or, depending on what you want to sort

var sortedResults = votingResults.OrderByDescending(v => v.PrecinctTotal);
```

Now you can print

```
var totals = new int[NumberOfCandidates];
foreach (VotingResult v in sortedResults) {
    Console.WriteL(v.Precinct + "\t\t");
    for (int cand = 0; cand < NumberOfCandidates; cand++) {
        Console.Write(v.Candidates[cand]  + "\t\t");
        total[cand] += v.Candidates[cand];
    }
    Console.WriteLine(v.PrecinctTotal);
}
Console.WriteLine("\nTOTAL RESULTS\t\t");
for (int cand = 0; cand < NumberOfCandidates; cand++) {
     Console.Write(totals[cand]  + "\t\t");
}
Console.WriteLine();
```

Don't forget this line at the top of your code as we are using LINQ for sorting and summing.

```
using System.Linq;
```

---

You can also use a `SortedList` of cause. This is of an advantage if you need to access the sorted result several times or if you want to add additional entries to the list and you want the list to be sorted all the time, not just at the end.

```
var sortedList = new SortedList<string, VotingResult>();

...
sortedList.Add(votingResult.Precinct, votingResult);
...
```

Or if you want to sort by row totals in descending order

```
var sortedList = new SortedList<int, VotingResult>();

...
sortedList.Add(-votingResult.PrecinctTotal, votingResult);
...
```

The rest remains the the same, except that you can drop the sorting part and you would have to loop through `sortedList.Values`.

---

There are many ways to do it, but any case it is advantageous to create a class for the list entries, as it allows you to keep all data to be sorted together.